# Intelligent purely functional sets

Tags: performance, haskell, data-structures, f#, immutability

Set computations composed of unions, intersections and differences can often be expressed in many different ways. Are there any theories or concrete implementations that try to minimize the amount of computation required to reach a given answer?

For example, I first came across a practical application of this when trying to decompose atoms in a simulation of an amorphous material into neighbor shells where the first shell are the immediate neighbors of some given origin atom and the second shell are those atoms that are neighbors of the first shell not in either the first shell or the one before it:

```
nth 0 = singleton i
nth 1 = neighbors i
nth n = reduce union (map neighbors (nth(n-1))) - nth(n-1) - nth(n-2)
```

There are many different ways to solve this. You can incrementally test of membership in each set whilst composing the result or you can compute the union of three neighbor shells and use intersection to remove the previous two shells leaving the outermost one. In practice, solutions that require the construction of large intermediate sets are slower.

Presumably an intelligent set implementation could compose the expression that was to be evaluated and then optimize it (e.g. to reduce the size of intermediate sets) before evaluating it in order to improve performance. Do such set implementations exist?

Comment: Well, I guess SQL databases with single-column tables are essentially sets with a query-language-optimizer. I have no idea whether any of them have optimizations that would apply to this query, though... or even whether SQL is an exciting enough language to be able to express this query.

Comment: I looked at perhaps a dozen a few years ago and the answer was "no" for these, with the notable exception of SQL query optimizers.

Comment: Sounds like C++ expression templates...

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point but, of course, I'm interested in in-memory collections.

Comment: @ildjarn Can you elaborate on that? Is that the stuff I was using to optimize array algorithms 10 years ago using the Blitz++ library by Todd Veldhuizen?

Comment: @Jon : Yes, you're thinking of the same, though the domain (not to mention the language) has evolved/matured a lot since then.

Answer (score 8):

Your question immediately reminded me of Haskell's stream fusion, described in [this paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401).  The general principle can be summarized quite easily: Instead of storing a list, you store a way to build a list.  Then the list transformation functions operate directly on the list generator, meaning that all the operations fuse into a single generation of the data without any intermediate structures.  Then when you are done composing operations you run the generator and produce the data.

So I think the answer to your question is that if you wanted some similarly intelligent mechanism that fused computations and eliminated intermediate data structures, you'd need to find a way to transform a set into a "co-structure" (that's what the paper calls it) that generates a set and operate directly on that, then actually generate the set when you are done.

I think there's a very deep theory behind this concept that the paper hints at but never spells out, and if somebody else here knows what it is, please let me know, because this is very relevant to something else I am doing, too!

Comment: Well, this is called *codata*. Instead of constructing data with constructors, you tear up codata with "destructors". Lists are data, streams are codata. (category theory lovers: data are initial algebras, codata are terminal coalgebras). Intuitionistic real numbers (as "cauchy sequences" N -> Q) are codata.

Comment: Fusion optimizations are encodings of properties of recursive co-algebras. The different algebraic laws, when implemented as rewrites on the expressions, yield complexity improvements. Hinze et al. cover the theory http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/IFL10.pdf .

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  This helps immensely.